Django - Adding a favicon through urls.py
I'm trying to get my favicon to appear in the browser tab. The favicon.ico is correctly placed in the static files directory, and I can access it directly via http://localhost:8000/static/favicon.ico. I am trying to get it to work without adjusting the html header.
The favicon.ico is located inside of project/core/static
my urls.py is located inside of project/core
I have this code inside of my settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

I have this code inside of my urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('favicon.ico'))),
    ]


Django version - 5.0.1
Verified that I can access the favicon directly via http://localhost:8000/static/favicon.ico.
The expected behaviour is the favicon displayed on the browser tab.
